# Delete an element list recursively

Tags: list-manipulation, performance-tuning, filtering

I have a list, say `{10,9,8,7,2,3,5,4,3,2,1}`

What I want to achieve is to delete the elements that are not in decreasing order recursively. Namely, the output should be `{10,9,8,7,5,4,3,2,1}`, which deletes `{2,3}` in the list.

I am seeking some elegant and efficient way to do so. Naively, I have thought about these methods:

1. Using a loop and starting from the first element, compare the current element with the next element. Remove the current if `current < next`, and move the pointer to the previous element. Do it recursively until the next is smaller than the current. Clearly, this is a procedural programming which is not preferable in Mathematica.
2. Using `Nest[]`. First do `Difference[list]` and remove all the positive elements. Update list and do it recursively until the `Difference[list]` are all negative.
3. Using `Nest[]` and find the minimal peaks in the list, delete the peak step by step.

All these methods use loops or `Nest` and hence are not very efficient. I am wondering if there is a built-in function that can do this efficiently.

Comment: I don't think that there is a built-in method for this specific task. But this one is reasonably simple, isn't it? `FixedPoint[Delete[#, Position[Differences[#], _?Positive]] &, #] &`?

Comment: Well, this seems faster than loop or nest.

Comment: @JakePan - what would you like the output for a list like `{10, 9, 11, 12, 8, 7, 2, 3, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1}` to be?

Comment: @JasonB.  Should be {12, 8, 7, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1}

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
list = {10, 9, 11, 12, 8, 7, 2, 3, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1};
list //. {a___, b_, c_, d___} /; c > b -> {a, c, d}
(* {12, 8, 7, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1} *)
FixedPoint[Pick[#, Append[UnitStep[Differences[#]], 0], 0] &, list]
(* same output, slightly faster *)
Reverse@DeleteDuplicates[Reverse@list, Greater]
(* same output, slightly faster *)
```

Also, (a comment by [Henrik Schumacher](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/38178)),

```
FixedPoint[Delete[#, Position[Differences[#], _?Positive]] &, #] &@list
(* same output *)
```

and (a comment by [chuy](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/237))

```
list //. {x___, PatternSequence[a_, b_] /; (a < b), y___} :> {x, b, y}
(* same output *)
```

Comment: `ReplaceRepeated[{x___, PatternSequence[a_, b_] /; (a < b) , 
   y___} :> {x, b, y}]@list` as well.

Answer (score 6):

It looks like you want the longest descending sequence starting with the max value. I think the following will do what you want:

```
descendingSequence[list_] := LongestOrderedSequence[
    list[[First @ Ordering[list,-1] ;; ]],
    Greater
]
```

Examples:

```
descendingSequence[{10, 9, 8, 7, 2, 3, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1}]
descendingSequence[{10, 9, 11, 12, 8, 7, 2, 3, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1}]
```

> {10, 9, 8, 7, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1}
>
> {12, 8, 7, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1}

Comment: Although you're probably right and the OP might actually really want something related to the LIS, that is not quite what is described in the original question. For example, take

    {10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 7, 8, 7, 6, 7}

Then your solution yields {10,9,8,7,6} whereas the original procedure gives {10,9,8,8,7,7} . Note that this is not solved simply changing Greater -> GreaterEqual, which would then yield {10,9,8,7,7,7,7}

Answer (score 3):

```
f1 = FixedPoint[SequenceReplace[#, {a_, b_} /; Less[a, b] :> b] &, #] &;
```

And a faster variation of AccidentalFourierTransform's second method:

```
f2 = Reverse @ DeleteDuplicates[FoldList[Max, Reverse @ #]]&;

f1[{10, 9, 8, 7, 2, 3, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1}]
```

> {10, 9, 8, 7, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1}

```
f1[{10, 9, 11, 12, 8, 7, 2, 3, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1}]
```

> {12, 8, 7, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1}

```
f1[{10, 9, 11, 12, 8, 7, 2, 3, 5, 4, 3, 15, 2, 1, 20}]
```

> {20}

```
f1 @ # == f2 @ # & /@ 
{{10, 9, 8, 7, 2, 3, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1}, 
{10, 9, 11, 12, 8, 7, 2, 3, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1} ,
{10, 9, 11, 12, 8, 7, 2, 3, 5, 4, 3, 15, 2, 1,20} }
```

> {True, True, True}

**Note:** Carl's method both produces longer lists and is faster than any of the methods posted so far (except AccidentalFourierTransform's first method).

Comment: Crazy man.......

Comment: i tried with a 30000 element long list. Carl's method was the first to complete the task (up to 1 order of magnitude faster than accidental's  FixedPoint[Pick[]]method)

Comment: @Alucard, it seems that  it depends on how much variation there is in the input list. With `SeedRandom[1];
lst1=RandomSample[Range[30000]];
First/@{RepeatedTiming[fixedPointPick[lst1];],
RepeatedTiming[descendingSequence[lst1];]}` I get 
`{0.0015, 0.038}`, The results are similar with `lst2 = RandomInteger[100000,30000]`. With `lst3 = RandomInteger[100,30000];` the timings are reversed: `{0.0014, 0.00015}`.

Answer (score 2):

```
la = {10, 9, 8, 7, 2, 3, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1};
```

Using `SequenceSplit (new in 11.3)`

```
Flatten @ SequenceSplit[la, {a_, b_} /; a < b]
```

{10, 9, 8, 7, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1}

```
lb = {10, 9, 11, 12, 8, 7, 2, 3, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1};

lc = Flatten @ SequenceSplit[lb, {a_, b_} /; a < b]
```

{10, 12, 8, 7, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1}

To start with the largest element we use `PositionLargest` (new in
13.2)

```
lc[[First @ PositionLargest @ lc ;;]]
```

{12, 8, 7, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1}

With `SequenceCases` we must append `-Infinity` to catch the last
element

```
First /@ SequenceCases[Append[-Infinity] @ la, {a_, b_} /; a > b, Overlaps -> True]
```

{10, 9, 8, 7, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1}

Answer (score 1):

```
FixedPoint[Delete[#, Position[ListConvolve[{-1, 1}, #], _?(# <= 0 &)]] &, list]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
alist = {10, 9, 8, 7, 2, 3, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1};
res = {10, 9, 8, 7, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1};

(Split[alist, Less] // Map[Last] ) == res
```

(* True *)

The above shows one step only (enough in this case) but it has to be wrapped in `FixedPoint` until the output becomes a strictly descending list.

---

*Visualization:*

To cook up an example showing the recursive operation, we start with a descending list and introduce a few shuffles.

```
SeedRandom[1];
blist = Range[20, 1, -1] // 
   SubsetMap[RotateLeft, #, RandomInteger[{1, 20}, 2]] & //
  SubsetMap[RotateLeft, #, RandomInteger[{1, 20}, 2]] &;

t = Most@FixedPointList[Last /@ Split[#, Less] &, blist];
```

> {{13, 19, 18, 17, 16, 20, 14, 15, 12, 11, 10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2,
> 1}, {19, 18, 17, 20, 15, 12, 11, 10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2,    1},
> {19, 18, 20, 15, 12, 11, 10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1}, {19,    20,
> 15, 12, 11, 10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1}, {20, 15, 12, 11, 10,    9,
> 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1}}

---

[image]