# Cannot delete list elements within (/;) condition scope

Tags: condition, elements

I encountered a problem when trying to delete list elements within the scope of **(/;) condition**. Although I used the directive `list=Delete[list,x]`, it still couldn't 'delete' the element.

I know there have been some answers which is in some degree similar to my question *"https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/173900/delete-an-element-list-recursively"*, but I want to explore the reason behind. I've made some simplification to focus the problem itself:
In my code, I use `FindPeaks` to get some peaks,

```
singularity=FindPeaks[curv,\sigma][[All,1]]
```

Let's assume {**3**, **49**} for example, now let's assume we want to exclude the point 3, I use the following:

```
f1[x_,argset_]:={argset=Delete[argset,x];ret=x-1}/;argset[[x]]<5;
For[p=1,p<Length[singularity](*{3,49}*),p++,p=f1[p,singularity][[1]]]
```

but it occurs errors like:

$\color{red}{Set:}$
**List{49,3} and {49} are not the same shape**

Is it related to the HoldPattern? I use

```
  DownValues[f1]
```

the HoldPattern is as follows:

```
    {HoldPattern[f1[x_,argset_]]:->{argset=Delete[argset,x];ret= x-1}/;argset[[x]]<5}
```

seems no problems. Can someone tell me what's wrong? How can I delete the elements within the scope of (/;) directive? Thanks in advance!

Comment: For the last line of code with `HoldPattern` are you trying to use `:>` or `->` ?

Comment: @  IntroductionToProbability. It's ' :>', sorry by mistake, thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The issue is that when a rule defined by `SetDelayed` is applied, all occurrences of matched symbols are replaced on the right hand side of the expression, no matter where they appear. So for example:

```
f[x_] := HoldComplete[x]

f[{4}]
(* HoldComplete[{4}] *)
```

Note that even within `HoldComplete`, the `x` was inserted. This means that in your expression, you'll end up with the following:

```
f1[1,{49,3}]
(* ---> *)
{{49,3}=Delete[{49,3},x];ret=x-1}/;{49,3}[[x]]<5
```

So before anything happens, the left side of the assignment is already replaced by the list `{49,3}`. The resulting `{49,3}={3}` is of course meaningless.

I don't know exactly what the goal of your actual code is, but the code from the question can be significantly simplified:

```
Select[singularities, #>5&]
(* {49} *)
```

As you can see, there is no need to repeatedly reassign the list or anything if you manage to restructure the code appropriately.

As a more direct fix of your problem, you might be interested in the various `Hold*` attributes, in this case, [`HoldRest`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/HoldRest.html):

```
singularity = {3, 49}
(* {3, 49} *)

Attributes[f1] = {HoldRest};
f1[x_, argset_] := {argset = Delete[argset, x]; ret = x - 1} /; 
   argset[[x]] < 5;
For[p = 1, p < Length[singularity](*{3,49}*), p++, 
 p = f1[p, singularity][[1]]]

singularity
(* {49} *)
```

Comment: Thanks! your explanatiion is quite clear. Now I understand it's because the SetDelayed exerts substitutions at the begining. I'll try the 'Select' method, it's better.